# Remove items that have a partial repeating name from database

Tags: r

I'm very new at this, so I'm sorry if this is a vague or stupid question. I have a database that has a column called filename and in that column, I have thousands of filenames like:

```
johnsmith_johnsmith
Deidre_D_johnsmith
C.C._johnsmith
lisasmith_johnsmith
debraclark_spy_guy
genejones_spy_guy
joycerichards_joycerichards
```

Essentially every name at the beginning of each filename is a customer and the name at the end is the person managing that file. I only need one file per manager.

Any file that has the same bit at the end like johnsmith_**johnsmith**, Deidre_D_**johnsmith**, lisasmith_**johnsmith** is something I usually want to have only ONE of. So, I would like to ideally have the option to view all in a set of matched "endings" and select which one(s) I'd like to keep and which I'd like to delete without having to eyeball all my filenames. I would like to view them before deleting so I can indeed make sure that each manager is represented so that two managers with the same name don't get deleted (I would then look at a variety of file attributes that are out of the scope of this question.)

How could I do this? My thought would be to do something like a percent match between all filenames, but since the surname Smith, for example, is extremely common, I would have to be so loose with my match that I feel like a percent match wouldn't be a good way to go about this, also given the size of the database, this would be a rather slow algorithm.

Ideally, I would end up with a column containing something like:

johnsmith_johnsmith
debraclark_spy_guy
joycerichards_joycerichards

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible start point using `str_extract` and `group`. You might want to check the `stringr` cheatsheet to understand the Regular Expressions used (https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf). Additionally, you might want to remove the `slice_head` part at the end of the script to manually select which entries you would like to delete.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Original df
df <- tibble(names = c("johnsmith_johnsmith",
"Deidre_D_johnsmith",
"C.C._johnsmith",
"lisasmith_johnsmith",
"debraclark_spy_guy",
"genejones_spy_guy",
"joycerichards_joycerichards"))

df |>
  # Extract pattern preceded by _ followed by at least two letters _ at least 1 letter and end of string
  # or preceded by _ followed by at least 1 letter and end of string
  mutate(end = str_extract(names, "(?<=_)[:alpha:]{2,}_[:alpha:]+$|(?<=_)[:alpha:]+$")) |>
  # Group by end of string
  group_by(end) |>
  # Retain only the first entry by each group of end
  slice_head()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   end [3]
  names                           n end          
  <chr>                       <int> <chr>        
1 johnsmith_johnsmith             1 johnsmith    
2 joycerichards_joycerichards     7 joycerichards
3 debraclark_spy_guy              5 spy_guy
```